# Print several inputs into different plain texts - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm working on a project in Android Studio where I have one EditText where the user will insert one word at a time, 10 times. Everytime the user writes a new input and clicks on the button it goes to a different TextView than the previous ones and different from the next ones.
How can I put the different inputs into the specific (different) TextViews?

[image]

Every TextView has a different sequencial ID like, word1, word2, etc.

I haven't done java in a long time, so I'm having problems with logic. I tried to do the following but the app crashes.

```
    gameword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wordj);

    public void onClick(View v) { 
printwords(gameword.getText().toString());
    }

            });

    public void printwords(String word) {
            String[] array = new String[10];
            TextView[] positions = new TextView[10];



        for (int i=0; i < 10; i++){
                array[i] = word;
                   positions[i].setText(array[i]);
               }

            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new array of `TextView`'s and `String` every time the button is clicked. Change your code to the code below and it should work.

1. Make your `int[] textViews` , `String[] array` & `int i = 0` class variables and then initialize them in `onCreate()` after `setContentView()`
2. In above code, `int[] textViews` is the array of ID's of `TextView`'s from your activity.
3. After doing that, change your code to following:

   ```
   gameword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wordj);

   public void onClick(View v) { 
       array[i] = gameword.getText().toString();
       YourActivity.this.findViewById(textViews[i]).setText(array[i]);
       i++;
   }
   });
   ```